# Routing angular 4/5 hiding components

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular4-router

new to routing with angular 4/5, I am following the angular tutorial on their website.
I have an angular application which I want to be able to have two separate pages. Right now main page is `localhost:8870/dr3-interface` and I want a new page with new components on `localhost:8870/dr3-interface/manage_cycles_instances`

My issue is when I click on my link `Manage cycles instances` it shows all my `app.component` components and not only the components I decided to show on my `/manage_cycles_instances`. I tried to hide them using `*ngIf` but without results. Any ideas?

app.component.html :

```
<div style="text-align:left">
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</div>

<nav>
  <a routerLink="/manage_cycles_instances" routerLinkActive="active"> Manage cycles instances</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<div *ngIf="router = '/dr3-interface'">
  <h2><d-table></d-table></h2>
</div>
<br/>
<form-upload></form-upload>
<br/>
<list-upload></list-upload>
```

app-routing.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule }              from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes }  from '@angular/router';

import { DataTableComponent }   from './datatable/data-table.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'manage_cycles_instances', component: DataTableComponent },
  /* TO DO : page error
  { path: '**', component: ... }
  */
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {
 //all material modules
} from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { DataTableComponent } from './datatable/data-table.component';
import { DetailsUploadComponent } from './upload/details-upload/details-upload.component';
import { FormUploadComponent } from './upload/form-upload/form-upload.component';
import { ListUploadComponent } from './upload/list-upload/list-upload.component';

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    //material modules
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DataTableComponent,
    DetailsUploadComponent,
    FormUploadComponent,
    ListUploadComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your routes should be this :

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dr3-interface', component: DrThreeComponent, children: [ // I don't know which component to use for this route
    { path: 'manage_cycles_instances', component: DataTableComponent },
  ]}, 
];
```

Because you want to have nested routes, you should make nested routes. Note that your `DrThreeComponent` should have a `router-outlet`, since it has children.

You won't need to use conditions in your code, because the router will handle the display of your components.

## Explanation :

You start by having an **index.html** file. It only contains a tag in its body, usually `app-root`. This tag will be **replaced** by your bootstraped component, which is usually `AppComponent`.

If you want to route your application, you will need to use the **router**. Several steps are required :

1 - Put a **router-outlet** tag in the component that will route others (here, app component)

2 - Create your routes (you did it, and I corrected it in my answer).

3 - in case of child routes (routes seprated by slashes, like yours), put a router outlet tag in every parent component, and a `children` property into the corresponding routes.

In your case, if we were to make a tree, this would look like this :

```
index.html
  |
  |--app component (with router outlet)
       |
       |--DrThree component (with router outlet)
            |
            |--ManageCycles component
```

So basically, **index will show app**, then **app will show DrThree**, then **DrThree will show ManageCycles**.

Comment: So I should create a new component with my main components in app.component (d-table, form-upload, list-upload) ? 
And when you say adding a `<router-outlet>` , you mean with a `<a link to /dr3-interface>` as the one I wrote for `/manage_cycles_instances`?

Comment: I don't know if you should write a new component, start by trying with existing ones such as `DataTableComponent` to see at least how it works ! And when I say you must add a router outlet, I mean you should add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the HTML of your component, because the router outlet will be replaced by the component you provided in your route configuration

Comment: understood but so in your example `DrThreeComponent`, is basically my `AppComponent` right ? And I already have a `<router-outlet>` inside my AppComponent , you mean adding one into my DataTableComponent? 
Sorry I'm kinda new to this, a bit confused

Comment: No, `AppComponent` is your app component. It is **bootstraped** (see *main.ts*), so you should not edit this. It should contain a router outlet, that will display the default route (in your case, none, but we can fix that). `DrThreeComponent` is another component, that will **have a router outlet too**. Maybe you want me to make a quick explanation on my post ?

Comment: could be great if you have time, just to understand how the whole thing works.

Comment: I did, if you still have questions, I'm here !

Comment: Ok it's clear thank you, but last question so, doing as you said, when `DrThree` show `ManageCycles`, I'll see only `ManageCycles` component and not `DrThree` + `ManageCycles` right ?

Comment: No, you will see both. If you don't want to see both, they should be brothers, not parents !

Comment: Ok, got it ! So it means if I want to have two separate pages I need to configure it like that `localhost:8870/dr3-interface` `localhost:8870/manage_cycles_instances` ?

Comment: Exactly :) (or you can use conditions with *ngIf, but **never surround a router outlet with a condition**)

Comment: It answered my question, thanks for the explanation ! :)

Comment: Nice answer, I managed to implement this myself without any issues. Is it possible to make it so you cannot navigate to `/dr3-interface` alone but instead must be `/dr3-interface/manage_cycles_instances`. I have the `router-outlet` in my version and it shows blank if i navigate to the child only and do not provide the router name for the grandchild.

Comment: It is possible, it depends on the routing you have implemented. If you want to achieve that, `/dr3-interface` must be a route without component, and the children must redirect. this would look like this : `{ path: 'd3-interface', children: [{path: 'manage-cycles', component: CyclesComponent}, {path: '', redirectTo: 'manage-cycles', pathMatch: 'prefix'}]}`

Comment: And sorry about the inline code, but format it to see it better @blueprintChris

Comment: thanks for your answer, i need to keep my component as it contains multiple other components within it. is there a way to keep the routing element implemented but hide it from the address bar? i want the reduce manual routing as much as possible and let my UI do the routing for the user.

Comment: What do you mean by hiding it ? You want to reduce the URL?

Comment: Meaning I don't want users to be able to  navigate via the address bar

Comment: Yeah well you can't do that. If you don't let the user type in the address, don't expect them to come to your website. Besides, what would happen if they put a page as favorite ?

Comment: They both are the same. You should let the user have access to the URL (that contains both your domain name and Angular routing). If you restrict it, not only it will be very difficult, but it won't be user-friendly. Furthermore, I won't be able to help you with that, so you will have to make another question.